# Quick method to create a file and open it

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, files

I want to create a markdown file and open it simultaneously

```
$ touch ~/Documents/Ubuntu/drafts.md; open ~/Document/Ubuntu/drafts.md
```

The solution is cumbersome, is there a shortcut to handle such a task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>There's no such shortcut,</strike> Apparently, one could use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> according to [Sebastian Stark's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048382/295286)

```bsh
touch ${filename}
xdg-open <alt>+<.>
```

If your shell uses `libreadline` ( [which `/bin/dash` on Ubuntu does not](https://askubuntu.com/q/704688/295286), but `bash` does ), then you can use that shortcut.

---

You can also create a file with shorter number of characters via `bash`:

```bsh
: > ${filename}; xdg-open ${filename}
```

In this case, `:` command is [built-in no-op command](https://askubuntu.com/q/549608/295286), which only returns exit status of 0 for success, but the trick here is that [shell creates new or truncates existing file](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067048/295286) designated by `${filename}`. `xdg-open` opens the said filename in default editor, since it will be just a plain file.

If you want to go even shorter, you can use `bash` history expansion feature to [reuse command parameters](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048302/295286):

```bsh
: > myfile.txt ; xdg-open !#:1
```

If portability is a concern, you should use `$_` for other shells. Of course, you can turn these into function or alias and call the alias or function name; call it something like `mko()` for "make and open":

```bsh
# function definition to put in ~/.bashrc
mko(){  : > "$1"; xdg-open !#:1 }
# call it as so:
mko ~/Documents/myfile.md
```

Making a function also has advantage in adding a template to the file, if you need that:

```bsh
mko(){ 
cat > "$1" <<EOF
### HEADING1
- bullet 1
- bullet 2
EOF 

xdg-open "$1" 
}
```

---

Sidenote: in case you also need to create directories along the path, you should use `mkdir -p`, see the [related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/927463/295286).

Sidenote No.2: [dessert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109095/295286) actually addresses a very fair point: most text editors do allow specifying a pathname for new file as one of their arguments. However, in cases where file has to exist - otherwise you get `No such file or directory` error - well, you can use this answer. Consider also that `>` truncates an existing file, so this can be useful where you want to quickly clear the file and start adding new content.

Answer (score 3):

#### Let the editor create the file

Most (if not all) editors automatically create the file if you open them with a filename of a nonexistent one. You can save the `touch` and simply open the new file directly, e.g.:

```
nano ~/Document/Ubuntu/drafts.md
vim ~/Document/Ubuntu/drafts.md
leafpad ~/Document/Ubuntu/drafts.md
```

This will create the new empty file and open it. Like your approach it will fail if a directory needs to be created in the process.

Comment: That's what I'd do, might want to do something like `nano $(mktemp -f XXXXXX.txt)` to make a random file (or use `date` to ensure no collisions). Set the one-liner as an `alias` in your `~/.bashrc` file, AND/OR set a hotkey to the alias/oneliner in your desktop manager.