# .bashrc alias for a command with fixed second parameter

Tags: bash

I would like to create an alias for the move command -

`trash='mv <some files> /home/$USER/.local/share/Trash/files'`

How do I make this work?

I want the destination to always be the same. But I want to be able to pass the files to be moved.

Comment: There is already a command-line interface to the trash: in 18.04 it's `gio trash` (in earlier versions of Ubuntu, `gvfs-trash`) i.e. you can just type `gio trash <some files>`. If that's really too long then you can alias it `alias trash='gio trash'`.

Comment: @steeldriver I thought of voting to close this as a duplicate of [Can I pass arguments to an alias command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626458/can-i-pass-arguments-to-an-alias-command) but I think your comment is really the best answer to the question here (and so it's not a duplicate of that). Would you consider posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use function instead of alias, defined in `.bashrc`

```
nano ~/.bashrc 

# put inside .bashrc:
trash() { 
  for item in "$@" ; do
    echo "Trashing: $item" 
    mv "$item" /home/$USER/.local/share/Trash/files 
  done
}
```

Then in shell prompt you can use:

```
$ trash file1 file2
```

Comment: Don't forget to close shell and open again to make this work

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` works too

Comment: You don't need a loop: `trash() { mv "$@" destination; }`

Answer (score 5):

You can only *append* arguments to an alias. Fortunately, `mv` allows you to do this, [with the `-t` option](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/mv.1.html)

```
alias trash='mv -t ~/.local/share/Trash/files'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a bash script and run that script with an alias.

trash.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

for arg in $*; do
    mv $arg /home/$USER/.local/share/Trash/files
done

exit 0
```

.bashrc:

```
alias trash="/path/to/script/trash.sh"
```