# Why is my alias from .bashrc not working?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, tar, alias

I've written a line in .bashrc

`alias untar='sudo tar –xvzf'`

Now, when I use "untar" in bash I get the error:

```
untar filename.tar.gz

tar: invalid option -- '�'
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

However when I use the actual command instead of the alias

`sudo tar –xvzf filename.tar.gz`

It works fine.

I did run `. ~/.bashrc`, so the alias is "known" (or however you'd call it). Which is also evident form the error message which acknowledges it's a tar command.
There's other aliases in bashrc which still work fine.

So, why isn't my alias working?

Comment: You will likely want to use a function rather than an alias. [This answer should give you what you need](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135732/1222991) 

Comment: @MarkRensen, you should skip `-z` and let `tar` decide on what decompression to use.

Comment: +1 for the tip by @bac0n. I adopted it in my answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your alias has a bad character, not the standard ASCII symbol (minus sign) but another one, which by some fonts is rendered as a longer dash.

This alias works for me

```
alias untar='sudo tar -xvf'
```

---

```
$ printf '-'|hexdump -C
00000000  2d                                                |-|
00000001
$ printf '–'|hexdump -C
00000000  e2 80 93                                          |...|
00000003
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. It looked like - but it was not -. It's like the problem with the greek question mark.

Comment: You are welcome @MarkRensen. I'm glad that I could spot it: Kudos to the font in my terminal window.

Comment: you should be able to do `printf %x\\n "'–"`

Comment: `printf '%b\n' \\U$(printf '%x\n' "'–")` should give you a full circle.

Comment: @bac0n, nicer and simpler commands than mine , but maybe not as good as explanation as with the explicit 'hexdump'.