# Loading and modifying an alias in command line

Tags: command-line

In order to speed up typing of a long command, we can make an alias of a command, e.g.

```
alias remcopy='scp user@123.45.67.89:/home/file.txt /home/user/'
```

And we type `user` this exact command will be run.

However, is it possible only to load the command and then modify it according to the current need, e.g.

```
scp user@123.45.67.89:/home/file.txt /home/user/addeddir/
```

Comment: It sounds like what you are really asking is [Can I pass arguments to an alias command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626458/can-i-pass-arguments-to-an-alias-command)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can start various modifications of the command.

- an alias can have a parameter, for example

  ```
  alias remcopy='scp user@123.45.67.89:/home/user/file.txt'

  remcopy targetname
  ```

  where `targetname` is selected a run time.
- a function is more flexible than an alias. It can be a single line or big like a whole shellscript file.

  ```
  function remcopy () { scp user@123.45.67.89:/home/user/file.txt /home/user/"$1" ; }

  remcopy
  remcopy addeddir
  ```

  which can be used without a parameter and with a parameter (in order to change the name of the target file.

  You can store a small function in `~/.bashrc` like you store aliases.

Comment: This might also be handy: `remcopy() { ssh host:remotefile "${1:-/home/user}"; }` to provide a default value if there's no specified value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to accomplish this.

For example:

```
alias something='nano ${1}'
something test.txt
```

Will open test.txt in nano for writing

Comment: ... only because `${1}` likely expands to nothing. So it's functionally equivalent to `alias something='nano'` - it's not actually passing the argument.

Comment: This has not been my experience. I tried to post a code block but multi-line code block doesn't seem to work in a comment

Comment: Try this: `set -- test1.txt; something test2.txt` -- what happens here?

Comment: markdown formatting in comments is very basic. You could add the information to your answer.