# Turning command into alias, what characters to escape?

Tags: bash, alias

I use the following command to count lines of code (skipping blank lines and comments) in python scripts:

```
sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' *.py | wc -l
```

This works just fine, and I am trying to turn this into an alias.

Seems that I am not escaping some characters properly, because this:

```
alias loc="sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' \$1 | wc -l"
```

does not work.

Comment: You problem isn't to do with characters needing to be escaped, aliases just don't support positional parameters like `$1`. See for example [Can I pass arguments to an alias command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626458/can-i-pass-arguments-to-an-alias-command)

Comment: @steeldriver Aha, I see! Thank you! I changed it to:
`loc() {
  sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' $1 | wc -l
}`

but calling this with: loc *.py does not produce the same output I expected, what am I doing wrong here?

When I call, in the terminal: `sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' *.py | wc -l` it produces a different result.

Comment: When you run `loc *.py` the shell expands `*.py` and passes the result to `loc`, where you only use `$1` (i.e. the first matching file). Try changing `$1` to `"$@"`.

Comment: @steeldriver You were right, $@ did the trick, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of steeldriver in the comments, I've created a function instead

```
loc() {   sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' $@ | wc -l }
```

which solved my problem

Comment: should quote "$@" or it will break on space