# Adding new runtime flag / options to commands in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, docker

I am trying to figure out how to add new runtime flags to commands that are run from the terminal.

For eg. : I have recently started experimenting with Docker and find it tedious to clean up exited containers by copy pasting IDs. I want to add a command line option `clean` to the `docker` runtime, so that when I run `docker clean` (or perhaps `docker --clean` if we're going that way) I can internally map it to run a cleanup command with already supported options by the docker runtime (namely `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)`) Is it possible to establish such a mapping?

I know one option is to use aliases, however aliases don't allow for having spaces / command line flags in the alias names, to the best of my knowledge. Similarly, shell functions don't help because they override the entire functionality (or perhaps I'm doing it wrong). I have wanted to explore this possibility for a while, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably what you need is a *shell function* - see [Aliases - able to pass arguments?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218630/aliases-able-to-pass-arguments)

Comment: Edited the original post. Functions don't help because they don't really allow me to add options to pre-existing executables. Instead it ends up overriding everything.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a bash function with the same name as an executable, and have it process your additional parameter and call the original function unambiguously using the `command` builtin. From `man bash`:

```
command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
       Run  command  with  args  suppressing  the normal shell function
       lookup. Only builtin commands or commands found in the PATH  are
       executed.
```

To illustrate,

```
function ls() { 
  case "$1" in 
    "foo")  shift
            echo "do new thing with remaining args: $@" 
            ;; 
    *)      command ls "$@"
            ;;
  esac
}
```

Then

```
$ ls -ltr --color=always
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 steeldriver steeldriver 4096 Sep 17 08:16 subdir1
drwxrwxr-x 2 steeldriver steeldriver 4096 Sep 17 08:17 subdir2
drwxrwxr-x 2 steeldriver steeldriver 4096 Sep 17 08:17 subdir3
```

works as normal, whereas

```
$ ls foo -ltr --color=always
do new thing with remaining args: -ltr --color=always
```

(you may need to `unalias` the `ls` command in order to try this out).

Obviously a real-world implementation should do proper error checking - perhaps using `getopts` to process the entire command line rather than a simple switch/case on `$1`.

---

Alternatively (and more traditionally) you could achieve the same by writing a *wrapper script* and placing it somewhere that comes earlier in your `$PATH` than the original executable (such as `/usr/local/bin` or `$HOME/bin`). Within the wrapper, refer to the original executable by its absolute path.

Comment: I took inspiration from (see `man less`) the `LESS` environment variable, and have grouped my favorite options in environment variables, so I do `pstree $PSTREE ...`, `dmesg $DMESG`, `sudo less $LESS ...`, and Profit!