# adding a second command to a python script with args

Tags: bash, scripts, python, alias

I have an alias for a python script that basically converts some files into another format, I want to be able to remove some intermediate format that this script generates as a post process after running the python script.

My alias to my python script looks like this:

`alias convert='python /filepath/convert.py'`

I run it like this within the directory containing the files I want to convert:

`convert *.RW2`

The script converts all .RW2 files into .tiff files but generates an intermediate .dng file which I don't need to keep, it's a temp file.

How would I simply append a delete to the alias? If I modify the alias it seems to interfere with the arguments for the .py script, for example this does not work:

`alias convert='python /filepath/convert.py && rm *.dng'`

Comment: It seems cleaner and more maintainable to edit your python script to handle the deletion. The script likely has a variable for the correct filename, so you needn't rely upon wildcards.

Comment: I didn't write the original python script and I would need to brush up on my python in order to do that. Thanks for your suggestion, it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Probably the "cleanest" way to solve this is to modify the `convert.py` script to clean up after itself.*

An alias is a simple text replacement macro - so your example will expand to something like

```
python /filepath/convert.py && rm *.dng file1.RW2 file2.RW2 file3.RW2 ...
```

which is obviously going to be incorrect. For anything more complex than a simple text substitution you should use a shell function instead ex.

```
convert() {
  python /filepath/convert.py "$@" && rm -- *.dng
}
```

or perhaps

```
convert() {
  python /filepath/convert.py "$@"
  for f; do 
    rm -- "${f%.*}.dng"
  done
}
```

(although you may want to choose a different name since there's already an ImageMagick command with the name `convert`).

See also [Aliases - able to pass arguments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218630/aliases-able-to-pass-arguments)

Comment: +1 and thank you for mentioning the _ImageMagick_ command. I'd like to beat them for chosing such a general term for such a special command.

Comment: @PerlDuck not quite as much as whoever named the `script` utility ;)

Comment: ``@steedriver`` this worked a treat - thanks so much. I need to understand the syntax better so I can learn this. Any suggested reading would be very welcome.