# Custom alias to run and compile .c file

Tags: command-line, bash, gcc, c, alias

I'm trying to create custom alias to to compile and run my .c files in one command. I tried to add this line in /.bashrc_aliases `alias runc='gcc $1 -lm && ./a.out'` however I get an error and it seems like the .c file doesn't get passed to the gcc. Any help apreciated.

Comment: See [Aliases - able to pass arguments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218630/aliases-able-to-pass-arguments)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I pass arguments to an alias command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626458/can-i-pass-arguments-to-an-alias-command)

Comment: Maybe a Makefile might be a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can include a variable within an alias. And in any case, you cannot use a variable within single quotes, you'd have to use doublequotes instead.

This function should work. Place these lines in your `.bashrc` file or wherever you would put the alias.

```
runc () {
    gcc "$1" -lm && ./a.out
}
```

And don't forget to source your .bashrc file after you have saved your edits.

```
. ~/.bashrc
```